# Logstash csv file as timestamp

Tags: logstash

Trying to combine a date and time feild to a @timestamp.
Here is the csv file I am loading.

```
     Date,Time,SWR,RSSI(dB),RxBt(V),Cels(gRe),Tmp2(@C),RPM(rpm),Tmp1(@C),Rud,Ele,Thr,Ail,S1,S2,S3,LS,RS,SA,SB,SC,SD,SE,SF,SG,SH,
2016-02-21,04:11:14.640,30,75,5.2,23.4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
```

Here is the load conf:

```
     input {  
      file {
      path => "/home/bkelley6/flights/*.csv"
      type => "flights"
      start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {  
csv {
    columns => ["Date", "Time", "SWR", "RSSI(dB)", "RxBt(V)", "Cels(gRe)", "Tmp2(@C)", "RPM(rpm)", "Tmp1(@C)", "Rud", "Ele", "Thr", "Ail", "S1", "S2", "S3", "LS", "RS", "SA", "SB", "SC", "SD" ,"SE", "SF", "SG", "SH"]
    separator => ","
}

mutate {
    replace => [ "datetime", "%{Date} %{Time}" ]
    }

date {
   match => [ "datetime", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
   timezone => "America/New_York"
   target => "@timestamp"
  }
}
output {  
     elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        workers => 1
    }
}
```

Here is the error msessages:

```
Failed parsing date from field {:field=>"datetime", :value=>"Date Time", :exception=>"Invalid format: \"Date Time\"", :config_parsers=>"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", :config_locale=>"default=en_US", :level=>:warn}
Failed parsing date from field {:field=>"datetime", :value=>"2016-02-21 04:2016-02-21", :exception=>"Invalid format: \"2016-02-21 04:2016-02-21\" is malformed at \"16-02-21\"", :config_parsers=>"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", :config_locale=>"default=en_US", :level=>:warn}
Failed parsing date from field {:field=>"datetime", :value=>"2016-02-21 17:2016-02-21", :exception=>"Invalid format: \"2016-02-21 17:2016-02-21\" is malformed at \"16-02-21\"", :config_parsers=>"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", :config_locale=>"default=en_US", :level=>:warn}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The literal "Date Time" is probably coming from the header row of your CSV data.  "Date" ends up in %{Date} and "Time" ends up in %{Time}, which you then combine into one field and try to run through date{}.

Comment: Your other date values are poorly formatted ("2016-02-21 04:2016-02-21").  I would try a minimalistic config (start with just the csv) and sue a stdout{} output to make sure everything looks good first.

Comment: I can take all the data in fine, and I can get everything working. I just want the time and date as the @timestamp instead of the log file in date.

Comment: The error messages imply that 'datetime' is not set as you are expecting...

Comment: I agree, but how is this resolved?

Comment: As I suggested, go back to minimal config (input, csv, stdout output) and make sure csv{} is doing what you expect.  Add on incrementally from there.

Comment: I have done that, and everything parses correctly, i dont have a problem until i push it into elastic search.

Comment: And then add the mutate in, and see what [datetime] looks like...  keep going.

Comment: looks like the issue is with the input part. Everything is working properly.

Comment: Everything is working properly, but the input section.